# New object initializing as <null> not package location

Tags: java, object, model, initialization

I have two model classes but they are initializing differently.

One shows

```
org.model.Address@6b04062b[secondLine=<null>,country=<null>,firstLine=<null>,town=<null>,id=<null>]
```

The other just shows

```
null
```

Both initialized the same way

```
Address ad = new Address();

Region re = new Region();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciaited.

Comment: Shows how? where? and where is the code?

Comment: There is no way that `System.out.println(new Region());` returns null. Show us the code.

Comment: `System.out.println(new Region() + "...");`
`System.out.println(new Address());`

produces the following output:
   `<null>...`
    `org.model.Address@7a6b8c5d[[secondLine=<null>,country=<null>,firstLine=<null>,town=<null>,id=<null>]`

Comment: It seems you are talking about the textual representation that has been printed to the console. This is determined by how the [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) method of each class has been implemented.